# How to send android intent to MinecraftPE with mod file (.mcpack)?

Tags: java, android, minecraft

**I want to write a simple Minecraft PE mods loader (Java + Android Studio), but encoutered a problem.**
I thought that all i need is to copy mod file from my app resources to "/games/com.mojang/behaviour_pack/", but minecraft didn't see it!
Then i downloaded some mod loader from play market to have an example and noticed that this loader opens Minecraft after installing some mod, and after that, the game asks permission to manage my storage.

---

So, as I understand, i need to send some intent to minecraft with mod file, and it will manage  further by itself.
Code that i've already tried:

```
    String filepath = "android.resource://" + c.getPackageName() + "/" + filename;
    
            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
                //Tried also ACTION_SEND
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                String mime = c.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    
                PackageManager packageManager = c.getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                Log.i("Acivities:", activities.toString());
                // 'c' - Context
                c.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

List of avaliable activities to open mod file is null, so it just crashes.
**How can i solve this thing??

What am i doing wrong with this intent?**

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to simply copy mods to any folder on external storage and send a right intent, shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("minecraft://?import=" + filepath));
c.startActivity(intent);
```

where 'c' - Context, "filepath" - path to file in external storage.